# SOQL Alias for Count() not working

Tags: soql

I have this simple SOQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) taskCount, WhatId Id
FROM Task
WHERE What.Type = 'Opportunity'
GROUP BY WhatId
```

I get the "Id" column but for the Count() I'm getting a column named "Unknown_Field__1"

I've tried many different combinations, but it's always returning a non-named column. Any tips?

Comment: Please add the code getting the values from the aggregate results by editing your question.

Comment: I just tried this in Query Editor and Apex, both are returning the expected return value. The problem might be in how you're calling the query.

Comment: Thanks guys! I just figured out that via REST API it's working as desired. 
I was building the Query via https://workbench.developerforce.com/ and here is not possible to handle the alias.

Once again, thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that via REST API or Apex code it's working as desired.
I was building the Query via https://workbench.developerforce.com/ and the alias are not working as expected.